# Array of objects gives undefined

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

so I have this slickgrid function which adds changed values in a cell to an object.

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e,args) { 
                 //console.log('arguments',args.item);
               
                editedRows.push(args.items)
                 //console.log('arrayrows',editedRows)
             });
    
  }
```

when I try to add the Object to array `editedrows` it gives undefined.

the object looks like this :

```
   arguments {hours: "6U", Total_inspection: 1234, Total_losses: 12345}
```

I though you could just push an object into an array and create a array of objects ?
what am I doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it `args.item`, or `args.items`?

Comment: The _"the object looks like this: ..."_ has to be the output of `console.log('arguments',args.item)` (that's the only `.log()` with the string `"arguments"`), hence the name of the property is `item` and not `items`

Comment: I made indeed a typo I feel like a retard.... Thanks guys totally looked over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments does not have an `items` property, it has others like `hours` etc. You just push `undefined` into the array above, since `argumnets.items` is `undefined`.

If what you wnat to do is to push the object as it is into an array just push itself:

```
editedRows.push(args)
```

But if you want actually a different thing like pushing all the keys, values, or both into an array then you need one of the `Object` *static methods* like `keys`, `values` or `entries`.